# Using composition - should an exception be thrown if wrong type

Tags: php, oop, interface, composition

When using composition, if an object is not of the type of the interface should an exception be explicitly thrown.

An example would be:

```
$myObject = new MyConcreteTypeA();
```

Now, my interface is `MyInterface`.

So, should I check the type of `$myObjec`t to make sure it implements `MyInterface` before using and throw an error if it does not?

i.e.

```
if (! ($myObject instanceof MyInterface)) {
    throw new Exception('Invalid type');
}
```

Or is this just cruft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, should I check the type of `$myObject` to make sure it implements `MyInterface` before using and throw an error if it does not?  Or is this just cruft?

If you've gone out of your way to create an interface, and the thing that expects objects also expects that they implement that interface, then yes, you absolutely should check and complain.

Contrast your approach with [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).  In the Criticism section, it talks about confusion between two unrelated methods.  I'm going to adapt their example so it works with PHP instead of Python*:

> you could easily create a class called Finger, which expects a class implementing the `press()` method to take an action upon. However, a class called Trousers might also implement the `press()` method. With Duck Typing, in order to prevent strange, hard-to-detect errors, the developer needs to be aware of each potential use of the method `press()`, even when it's conceptually unrelated to what he or she is working on.

If it's absolutely critical that you only *ever* deal with Trousers when you try to `press()` them, then you must make that check.  If your code doesn't care what gets `press()`ed, as long as it *does* get `press()`ed, then you can discard your check.

<sup>* The original example uses a property and a method. Properties and methods in Python share the same namespace. Trying to use a property as a method is even more disastrous, but doesn't apply in PHP.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

PHP is not only [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing) but also [weakly typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Strong_and_weak_typing). What you are doing by checking `$myObject` implements a given interface is somehow supplementing the lack of a more structured typing system in the language. If you want to do it you can, but there are some issues that you may want to consider:

- The check that you are making will be executed at run time, so you are not shifting from dynamically typed to statically typed. In other words, if your check fails, it will still fail at run time.
- If you want to be consistent with that philosophy, you may need to add that sort of checks throughout your entire code. You may then consider moving to a [defensive programming style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming) (note: I'm note a fan of that style).
- You may also want to consider [PHP type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php).
- By doing that kind of checks you are going kind of against the PHP type philosophy, which is pretty much [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

From my point of view it is important to adopt a homogeneous work pattern through your entire code, so just putting some scattered `instanceof` or `is_a` in some methods is not a good practice. If you feel that PHPs type system is not good/safe enough for you, you may want to consider:

- If you can, switch to another language whose type system makes you more confortable (e.g. Java or C#).
- Rely on additional tools, like combining [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/) and [Validators](http://research.quanbit.com/category/validators/)[*] to give you more confidence on your code.

HTH

[*] Disclaimer: I work at Quanbit Research.